# setKeyboardAppearance for UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, keyboard

It is well know that the keyboard appearance of `UITextView` and `UITextField` can be set as following :

```
[self.textField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

But how could we set the keyboard appearance of a `UIWebView`?

Actually, here im using **ckeditor** for HMTL editing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom webview keyboard issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664984/custom-webview-keyboard-issues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not set the keyboard appearance for a UIWebView using Apple's UIKit APIs.

You can however specify the input type using html tags like so:

```
<input type="text" size="30" autocorrect="off" autocapitalization="on">
```

And here are the other parameters.

```
Text: <input type="text"></input>
Telephone: <input type="tel"></input>
URL: <input type="url"></input>
Email: <input type="email"></input>
Zip code: <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"></input>
```

More info in the Apple docs:

[Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually im using ckeidtor to edit html.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can set it for a `UIWebview`. `UITextView` and `UITextField` can become first responder but a `UIWebView` can not be first responder. So there are no property called  `keyboardAppearance` for UIWebview. Its just that its elements inside `UIWebview` can bring keyboard to show up and not the `UIWebview`.

Answer (score -1):

using any web page to load web view in xcode,it have default keyboard,thh key board contains done, next&previous buttons,next&previous used to move textfields