# Black Keyboard on iOS7

Tags: keyboard, ios7, uikeyboard

I can't seem to be able to get the keyboard to default to black in my code. I've tried the solutions in the other posts with no success. Not sure if I am missing something. I want it to apply to all view controllers so I want to put it in my app delegate. This is the code I believe should be doing the trick, but its not working for me.

```
textfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

Answer (score 15):

I don't know what your variable "textfield" is, but if it is an instance of a UITextField, then it will only set the keyboard appearance for that specific textField instance.

If on the other hand you want to set it for all UITextFields throughout your app use instead:

```
[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
```

somewhere after your appstart, e.g. application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in your app delegate.

Comment: Nope, I did just that too, 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];  ....
}

Comment: That's odd. It does it for me, just tested. Could it be by any chance, that you are using a UITextView and not an UITextField?

Comment: im just using uiwebview, no specification or implementation of uitextview or uitextfield.

Comment: If you're using a UIWebView, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13132557/1367622). At the moment, there's no way to set the keyboard appearance in a UIWebView.