# setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark (inside of a UIWebView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uikeyboard

My app is themed black. My app is primarily a `UIWebView`. The default light colored keyboard looks terrible and very much out of place in my app.

I have googled for hours on various days, and have yet to find a way to use the "dark keyboard" inside of a `UIWebView`.

*Is there anything I can do to get the dark keyboard - without having to use a UITextField?* I'm quite desperate to get the dark keyboard for my app.

I'm open to potentially grey area methods that may or may not get the app approved (not open to 100% certain it won't get approved methods).

Comment: I've been playing with "gray" area methods myself, and was unable to force a dark appearance keyboard on a webview. Somewhere in the `UITextInputTraits` **class**, even forced down and swizzled appearance is somehow overridden.

Comment: I was able to do this using: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23398487/1091751, but only for `keyboardAppearance`, couldn't get any other UITextInputTraits to work.

Comment: Tim, this worked perfectly. I just hope it would be able to get accepted into the App Store.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom webview keyboard issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664984/custom-webview-keyboard-issues)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no way to do it, see also this answer
[setKeyboardAppearance for UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132446/setkeyboardappearance-for-uiwebview)